# Windows Server 2008 NTP

Tags: windows-server-2008, ntp

How to set the NTP server used by Windows Server 2008?

Comment: What? Why? Who? When? Where? Which? How?  More info please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to **Start** menu, set the **time and date** in section **Clock, Language, and Region**, **Internet Time** tab, **Change settings** and put your ntp server in the Server field.

Comment: I have 2 Windows 2008 Servers, in one of them the "Internet Time" is missing

Comment: http://blog.tanist.co.uk/2009/04/internet-time-tab-missing-in-server-2008/

Comment: The tab is missing because the server joined the domain.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on why you're doing this.  If you're talking about a standalone server, follow the steps given in the other answers.  If you're in an AD environment, be aware that only the DC which holds the PDC emulator role should have an NTP server explicitly set; every other server (and client) should *not* have an NTP server set - *at all*.  This is required so that the correct domain-based NTP hierarchy will take effect.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773263%28WS.10%29.aspx

**This is why we need more info - we may be able to give you the correct answer to your specific question, but whether the answer is correct or dangerous for your environment will depend on your environment, and only you can tell us that.**

Comment: Can I follow up on this one - we've got two AD servers and both are configured to get their time from internet NTP servers. Are you saying this is incorrect? What's the consequences of this configuration?

Answer (score 0):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773263(WS.10).aspx

```
w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:<time server to use>
```

may do what you're asking.